# How can I check in R using dplyr the values of a vector if they correspond (exist) to a column of a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

Let's say I have a data frame in R that looks like this :

| var1 | lc |
| --- | --- |
| A | london |
| B | athens |
| C | amsterdam |
| D | new york |
| E | tokyo |
| F | barcelona |
| G | rome |
| H | mexico city |
| I | cairo |

```
var1 = c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I")
lc = c("london","athens","amsterdam","new york","tokyo","barcelona","rome","mexico city","cairo")
df = tibble(var1,lc);df
```

Now I have a vector of interest that contains some values that I have to check.

```
var2 = c("A","C","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M")
```

My condition of interest is that if the elements of the column vector var1 exist in the second vector (var2).

Ideally a want to mutate (dplyr phrase) a new column that will contain the output if this logical condition and must look like this.

| var1 | lc | condition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | London | TRUE |
| B | athens | FALSE |
| C | amsterdam | TRUE |
| D | new york | FALSE |
| E | tokyo | TRUE |
| F | barcelona | TRUE |
| G | rome | TRUE |
| H | mexico city | TRUE |
| I | cairo | TRUE |

How can I do it in R using dplyr ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use %in%

```
df %>% mutate(condition = var1 %in% var2)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.And if I wanted to see which of var2 are not matched in the var1?

Comment: `df %>% mutate(condition = !(var1 %in% var2))`